# Question about WinEdt

Tags: winedt

I am planning to write a book on project management. A colleague clued me in to LaTex as a platform in which to write this book (for ultimate self-publishing). So I realize I have a learning curve ahead of me but am willing to tackle it. However, I recall him saying (or my hearing) that I needed to get an editor called WinEdt. If so, is that a component of LaTex? Or a separate editor that I must get that works in conjunction with LaTex?

I have a copy of "The not so short introduction to LaTex" and a search shows no mention of WinEdt. So, did I misunderstand? Is this a component of LaTex that handles editing? Or do I need no such thing and LaTex is sufficient for writing/editing and it is all-in-one? If, however, I do need WinEdt where do I find it? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to something more revealing than the fact that it is a question. E.g. "Is WinEdt a component of LaTeX?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinEdt (download it from http://www.winedt.com/download.html) is an editor helping you to write LaTeX code and compile it later to get a resultung pdf file.

WinEdt needs an installed LaTeX system, for example MiKTeX (http://www.miktex.org).  Install first MiKTeX, then WinEdT. WinEdt is able to recognise that MiKTeX is installed and makes then configuration easier.

WinEDT and LaTeX are two parts working together ...

Comment: Ah-ha. So that resulting PDF file is, I assume, what goes to the e-publishing house? And they just take that and publish as is, plus or minus a few questions? Don't mean to get ahead of myself but just trying to better understand the end game.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks much for your answer, quick response. I'm just now reading the Latex book and it is quite informative. Thanks.